# Ruby property access that emulates nested hash brackets

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to imagine if it's possible to create a class that could emulate nested hash access, where the 'nesting' levels count would be arbitrary . For example:

```
fakeHash[:something][:other] # Results in single property call on fakeHash
```

Comment: What would the equivalent "property call" look like?

Comment: If the nesting level is arbitrary, then what decides, in the middle of `...[][]...` sequences, whether there are more `[]` to come or it is the time for it to return the property?

Comment: @Abe- just a function that could access all the keys as an array.

Comment: @sawa- I don't know- I would just want a way to capture all the bracketed keys, but this indeed may not be possible?

Comment: @Yarin I still can't tell what you're going for but if it's something like a struct check out this gem: https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't return the object recursively- rather, i need to be able to process all the keys at the root object level, and return a value from there.

Unfortunately no, there isn't a way. This is because the `[]` is a method and the only way to be able to call that method an unlimited number of times (possibly) is with recursion (which implies that you return the object that contains the method `[]` and not the final object).

And even if it existed it would be very bad design. Whatever you are trying to do with this, you are doing it wrong and the code that would be generated would be likely confusing for other programmers.

---

Of course you could always simulate something like the following:

```
class Nested
    def [](s)
        # do something with s
        return self
    end
end
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/UE4u7r)'s an example.

Comment: @Jeffrey- thanks, but this isn't what I need (didnt downvote you though)- I can't return the object recursively- rather, i need to be able to process all the keys at the root object level, and return a value from there.

Comment: Thought so, thanks. It's a hack for sure, and probably best I can't do it..